Why is my question opinion based and downvoted?
I asked about the rationale for defining a block size and number of blocks for various file interaction interfaces rather than just defining a number of bytes. Given how I see those in enough independent places, there is clearly some objective reason to do it, so my question is not opinion based in my opinion. Can it be reopened and undeleted, pretty please?
Edit: I have incorporated the suggestion in the answer.

Is asking "why" on language specifications still considered as "primarily opinion-based" if it can have official answers?

When you ask for reopening a question, get an answer how to improve it and then you don't react for a week or longer, don't be astonished when nothing happens. After a certain period close votes, reopen votes, delete and undelete votes will automatically age away.

I would try to reword your question the way you already did here on Meta:

What is the rationale for defining a block size and number of blocks for various file interaction interfaces rather than just defining a number of bytes? Given how I see those in enough independent places, there is clearly some objective reason to do it.

I cannot guarantee it will convince hardliners like gnat to reopen your question, but maybe 3 other community members with enough rep to cast an undelete vote.
Ok, after your last edit I took the freedom to reorder the questions paragraphs, improved the title and tags. I currently see two undelete votes and a few comments which could have been posted as an answer if the question wasn't closed and deleted so quickly. Two of the commenters have enough rep to cast an undelete vote as well. So all we can do is to wait now and hope the best.
Still, when one really wants a question to be reopened, one should try to respond quick - respond times of one or more weeks are making it likely for a question to vanish out of the minds of our community.

@user1345541, I agree with Doc. I voted to undelete your question and up-voted it. The question is published again.

It does need to be reopened, though, and I voted to reopen.
